# Fix IMacros Firefox Api error -9

Tags: firefox, imacros

Today my firefox suddenly crash when i am running a macro calling from php, and all the marco calling from php(using `iimPlay()`) does not work anymore, I have try to reinstall firefox and imacros, but it still did not fix any problem that I face, `iimOpen(-fx)` will return me an error code with -9, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you reinstall both 'iMacros Browser' and 'iMacros for Firefox'? (BTW, are you using 'php' instead of the [JavaScript Scripting Interface](http://wiki.imacros.net/Firefox#Javascript_Scripting_Interface) which is applicable in 'iMacros for Firefox'?)

Comment: yes i have reinstall both of them, i am using php to call firefox for example:
 
`public function Logout($username,$iim1){
$s = $iim1->iimSet('username',$username);
  $s = $iim1->iimPlay('Logout');
 }`

Comment: Perhaps, you can make your scripts work by means of applying only the Scripting Interface in 'iMacros for Firefox'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by installing a 32-bit Firefox, and not 64-bit Firefox